# Making a Linq query more efficient (.Net Core)

Tags: performance, linq

This query produces a group data by month for a javascript graph. The API calling this query currently takes about 6 seconds to run if there are 3 or 4 years of data to group.

Is there a way to make this query more efficient?

`pp3` is a list of projects and `zz` is the project budget data by day.

```
public static IQueryable<CombinedProjectFinancialSummary_Min> planned_bargraph(IQueryable<int> pp3, OneView_PPM db)
{
    var planned = from c in
                    (from x in pp3
                     join z in db.BudgetProfile on x equals z.ProjectRef
                     join bc in db.BudgetConfigs on z.ID equals bc.BudgetProfileId
                     join zz in db.Budgets on bc.Id equals zz.ConfigId                           
                     select new { SortDate = zz.MDate, Amount = zz.Cost }).ToList()
                     group c by
                              new { year = c.SortDate.Year, month = c.SortDate.Month }
                     into grp
                     select new CombinedProjectFinancialSummary_Min
                                {
                                    year = grp.Key.year,
                                    month = grp.Key.month,
                                    monthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(grp.Key.month),
                                    xSeries = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(grp.Key.month) + " " +  grp.Key.year,
                                    Amount = grp.Sum(t => t.Amount)
                                };

    return planned.AsQueryable();
}
```

Hoping to get this down to 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: Why are you returning it `.AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Have you actually measured, using `Stopwatch`, how long it takes to do the two parts of this method?

Comment: Naming `pp3` as `projects` and `zz` as `budgets` would save your time to write and our time to read and associate ;)

Comment: Are you sure that Groping executed in the sql server and not on the code side?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far, I've changed from the return IQueryable to IEnumerable.  As I develop mostly as a hobby, I was thinking that I'm missing something substantial in the logic of the query to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up reducing the query time by removing one of the joins

```
join z in db.BudgetProfile on x equals z.ProjectRef
```

This cut the execution time from 7 seconds to 1.5 seconds.